# Get Total Order by a customer

Tags: magento2, orders

In magento1, We are using below code to get the total orders by a customer

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
echo $orders->getSize();
```

How to get same in `magento2` ?. Any help would be appreciated.I want get this on order success page with using Object manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $select     = $connection->select()
        ->from($resource->getTableName('sales_order'), 'COUNT(*)')
        ->where('customer_id=?', $customerId);

    $totalOrderCount = (int) $connection->fetchOne($select);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   <?php

    protected $_orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory) {
     $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    // Customer email as a parementer of method
    public function getOrders($customerEmail)
    {
     //Retrieve all orders with this email address
     $orders = $this->_orderFactory->create()
            ->getCollection()
      ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $customerEmail);

     //Retrieve all order ids
     $orderIds = $order->getAllIds();
    }
```

Comment: Hi,It will also work but My need was using Object manager Directly.Thanks For help.